# Picking largest number form a list not working

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I am currently trying to make a module that takes a list of scores and their title and trying to find the biggest scoring one out of the list. The code I have seems to work some times while sometimes it doesn't. It's just a simple comparing module in python 2 but I cant get it to work.

EDITED:
So basically the output should be in the format of what command sec is it in and exactly what was the highest number in the list. But the actual output is "else none" which pops up if there is no increase or decrease in the whole list.

Actual output: "else none"

Expected Output: what_is_cmds 100.0

```
similarity_percent_lst = ["who_is_cmds", "50.0", "when_is_cmds", "15.0","what_is_cmds", "100.0", "where_is_cmds", "50.0", "personal_info_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "personal_emotion_cmds", "20.0", "personal_emotion_cmds", "40.0", "bye_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "100.0", "time_cmds", "60.0", "time_cmds", "75.0", "time_cmds", "50.0", "time_cmds", "50.0", "time_cmds", "100.0", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "50.0", "date_cmds", "40.0", "date_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "date_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "date_cmds", "50.0", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "weather_cmds", "50.0", "weather_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "weather_cmds", "33.33333333333333"]

biggest_percent_similarity = 50.0
biggest_percent_cmd_sec = "who_is_cmds"
# GETS THE BIGGEST OUT OF ALL THE ONES THAT WERE SIMILAR AND MAKES THAT THE FINAL CHOSEN COMMAND.
if len(similarity_percent_lst) > 2:
    for each_number in range(3, len(similarity_percent_lst),2):

        # if the n command in the similarity list is more than the n-1 command in the similarity list then this executes.
        if (similarity_percent_lst[each_number] > biggest_percent_similarity) == True:
            print "\n" + "similarity_percent_lst[each_number] > biggest_percent_similarity"
            print similarity_percent_lst[each_number] + ">" + str(biggest_percent_similarity)
            print "biggest_percent_similarity BEFORE: ",biggest_percent_similarity,str(each_number)
            biggest_percent_similarity = float(similarity_percent_lst[each_number])

            biggest_percent_cmd_sec = similarity_percent_lst[each_number - 1]

            print "biggest_percent_similarity NOW: ",biggest_percent_similarity,str(each_number)

            score = biggest_percent_cmd_sec + " " + str(biggest_percent_similarity)

        # if the n command in the similarity list is less than the n-1 command in the similarity list then this executes.
        elif (similarity_percent_lst[each_number] < biggest_percent_similarity) == True:
            print "\n" + "similarity_percent_lst[each_number] < biggest_percent_similarity"
            print similarity_percent_lst[each_number] + ">" + str(biggest_percent_similarity)
            print "biggest_percent_similarity BEFORE: ",biggest_percent_similarity,str(each_number)
            biggest_percent_similarity = similarity_percent_lst[each_number - 2]

            biggest_percent_cmd_sec = similarity_percent_lst[each_number - 3]

            print "biggest_percent_similarity: ",biggest_percent_similarity,str(each_number)

            score = biggest_percent_cmd_sec + " " + str(biggest_percent_similarity)

        else:
            score = "\n" + "else none"

elif len(similarity_percent_lst) < 2:
    score = "\n" + "elif none"

else:
    print "\n" + "it aint two numbers"
        biggest_percent_cmd_sec = similarity_percent_lst[0]

    biggest_percent_similarity = similarity_percent_lst[1]

    score = biggest_percent_cmd_sec + " " + str(biggest_percent_similarity),str(each_number)

print similarity_percent_lst
print "score: " + score
```

Comment: Could you please post some examples with expected and actual output?

Comment: I think `similarity_percent_lst` is the input and the titles and scores alternate. Can I suggest that instead of storing all your input in one array where you mix types of data that you have a list of tuples (or objects) where each one contains its relevant data. `input = [("who_is_cmds", 50.0), ("when_is_cmds", 15.0)]`

Comment: Your code will never work like this as you haven't indented your for loop.

Comment: Are you trying to find the string associated with the highest number?

Comment: Yes i am trying to see which one has the highest value and get the string associated with it @StephenPaulger

Comment: Sorry it was mistake on copying the code over onto here @Flyte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
orig_input = ["who_is_cmds", "50.0", "when_is_cmds", "15.0","what_is_cmds", "100.0", "where_is_cmds", "50.0", "personal_info_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "personal_emotion_cmds", "20.0", "personal_emotion_cmds", "40.0", "bye_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "100.0", "time_cmds", "60.0", "time_cmds", "75.0", "time_cmds", "50.0", "time_cmds", "50.0", "time_cmds", "100.0", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "50.0", "date_cmds", "40.0", "date_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "date_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "date_cmds", "50.0", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "weather_cmds", "50.0", "weather_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "weather_cmds", "33.33333333333333"]

cleaned_input = [(orig_input[i], float(orig_input[i+1])) 
                 for i in range(0, len(orig_input), 2)]

print max(cleaned_input, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

`orig_input` is the same as your `similarity_percent_lst`. First we parse that array into a list of 2-tuples. A single 2-tuple might look like `("when_is_cmds", 15.0)`. We also convert the string of the score into a float.

Then we use `max`, passing it a function that returns the number so that `max` can easily compare the items.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is loosely based on the [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and the first example in [this abarnert's blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html)

```
spcl = iter(similarity_percent_lst)
max_name, max_value = max(zip(spcl,spcl), key=lambda tpl:float(tpl[1]))
```

1. We make an iterator over the list `similarity_percent_lst`
2. The elements in the list are grouped 2-by-2: `zip(spcl,spcl)`
3. The max is found using the optional `key` argument of the [`max` builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) (remembering to convert from strings to floating point numbers...).

The idiom `zip(it,it)` that works to *pair* items in an iterable leads to the `grouper` recipe.
I forward you to  the references in the first paragraph for a complete discussion of it.

Comment: Everyone should learn how that recipe works at some point (someone asked on SO a year or two ago, and the question got closed as too broad, so [I wrote a whole blog post about it](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html)…). But I don't think the OP is going to put the effort into learning now, so maybe the slicing answer is better. (I upvoted both.)

Comment: The issue you've  raised (OP not going...) is an important one, I'll try to add simpler answers when I'll see the need in the future, Tx.

Comment: StephenPaulger already added the other one, and it's definitely worth having both here. (Even if the OP doesn't get your answer, someone else with the same problem might, after all.)

Answer (score 0):

Here come a solution to your problem relying on the standard python library `max` function.

```
similarity_percent_lst = ["who_is_cmds", "50.0", "when_is_cmds", "15.0","what_is_cmds", "100.0", "where_is_cmds", "50.0", "personal_info_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "personal_emotion_cmds", "20.0", "personal_emotion_cmds", "40.0", "bye_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "100.0", "time_cmds", "60.0", "time_cmds", "75.0", "time_cmds", "50.0", "time_cmds", "50.0", "time_cmds", "100.0", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "time_cmds", "50.0", "date_cmds", "40.0", "date_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "date_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "date_cmds", "50.0", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "date_cmds", "33.33333333333333", "weather_cmds", "50.0", "weather_cmds", "66.66666666666666", "weather_cmds", "33.33333333333333"]

def fromList2tuple(listOfPairs):
    """ Take a list that contains pair of element and return them in tuples [a,b,c,d]-> [(a,b), (c,d)] """
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(listOfPairs)-1, 2):
        result.append((listOfPairs[i], listOfPairs[i+1]))

    return result

def biggerTuple(listOfTuple, index):
    """ 
    Returns the bigger tuple of a list of tuple considering the order is determined by the element whose the index is given.
    [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', -2)] , 0 ->  ('c', -2)
    [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', -2)] , 1 ->  ('b',  2)
    """
    #define a function that return the element at the index of the tuple.
    orderingFunction = lambda x: x[index]
    #then use ti to order the results
    return max(listOfTuple, key=orderingFunction)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    tuples = fromList2tuple(similarity_percent_lst)
    print(biggerTuple(tuples, 1))
```

Executing this code I got the following result : `('time_cmds', '75.0')`